# Why is the final keyword used here?

Tags: java

I learn java from book "Java. How to Program" P. & H. Deitel
On page 216 there is an example which used `final` in one of variable

```
private static final Random randomNumbers = new Random();
```

As far as I understand declaration final in variable mean, that variable is kind of constant, that mean when is initialized you cant change it anymore.
But above object(variable) is used in program twice to return random number

```
int die1 = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt( 6 );
int die2 = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt( 6 );
```

and it returns 2 different (random) values.
I think I lost something here. Program works good, but I dont understand what was purpose to use `final` in object declaration?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`final` means that the *variable* cannot change its value here - and indeed it can't and doesn't.

Here the value of the `randomNumbers` variable  is a *reference* to an instance of `Random`. It refers to the same instance, even though that instance produces (potentially) different numbers each time you call `nextInt`.

It's important to differentiate between a variable not changing value, and the object it refers to not changing internal state. As another example, you could have something like this:

```
public class Person {
    private final List<Person> friends = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public void addFriend(Person friend) {
        friends.add(friend);
    }

    ...
}
```

Here we only have one list - you can never change `friends` to refer to a different object - but we can still mutate the list that the variable refers to.

Comment: SO that mean if later in program I would try to change `randomNumbers` for example `randomNumbers = Random(123456)` it shows error in compilation?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Jon has said. 
The purpose of final was to avoid having two instances of Random class referred by randomNumber variables at different stage of application lifecycle. On most obvious purpose is that it is to avoid unnecessary object creations. However the most important (and logical) reason of making it final is to keep the fairness of  randomNumbers high. What I mean is that when you call nextInt in succession on randomNumbers then the result returned has to be unique, random and different from previous results with highest probability. Suppose you do not make it final then another instance of Random at later stage may start giving duplicate values when compared to results of previous instance of Random. To avoid this its necessary to make randomNumbers final

Comment: If I can accept 2 answers as answer to my question I would accept your as well. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

one word, when you make a **reference type or a primitive type final its immutable.** i.e., you cant change the value anymore.

> As far as I understand declaration final in variable mean, that
>   variable is kind of constant,

This is only half right, if you mark a variable final it doesn't necessarily mean that its constant. marking a variable with **static final** makes it a constant.

Answer (score 2):

**-** Making a variable final will indicate that the value of this variable canNot be changed.

`private static final Random randomNumbers = new Random();`

**-** In the above line, `randomNumbers` is an **Object Reference Variable** of type `Random` and as its being marked `final` it will **always be latched on to that Object of type Random.**

**-** Its very important to note here is that the Random object is not locked but the **Object Reference Variable** `randomNumbers` is **locked with that specific Random Object.**

**Note:**

`final variable` : Its value canNot be changed

`final method` : It canNot be overridden

`final class` : It canNot be extended

`final Parameter` : Its value canNot be changed which it receives from caller's argument

`final Object Reference Variable` : It canNot refer to any other object, other than the one its currently referring to

Comment: So in my case this is `final Object References Variable`, yes?

Answer (score 2):

Final means that you cannot change the referace variable once it is initiailized

```
For example

final Object obj = new Object();  //initialized 

now that doesnot mean that u cant call methods on obj

obj.someOperation1() //allowed
obj.someOperation2() //allowed
obj.anyOperationAnyTime() //allowed


But u cant assign new object to referance obj
final Object obj = new Object();  //initialized 
obj =  new Object() //now allowed , you cant make obj to point to new referance
```

Answer (score 0):

the type of randomNumbers is Random. That is randomNumbers  is a final object. Any other Random objects cannot be assigned to it. And you are just calling a method of that randomNumbers Object twice.

Answer (score 0):

setting the Random reference (randomNumbers) as final implies that you cannot assign another value to this particular reference.

That is, both of the following statements would be checked/reported at compile-time itself.

```
a. randomNumbers = new Random(); 

b. Random someOtherRandomNumbers = new Random(); 
   randomNumbers = someOtherRandomNumbers;
```